# WinJS.Promise Not Working as I'd Expect

Tags: javascript, windows-8, commonjs

I am working in a Windows 8 JavaScript app and a WinJS.Promise is not working as I'd expect. Here's my async method...

```
function MyFiveSecondFunctionAsync() {
    return new WinJS.Promise(function (c, e, p) {
        var start = new Date().getTime();
        var delay = 5000;
        while (new Date().getTime() < start + delay) p();
        c();
    });
}
```

And here's what I'm calling it with...

```
document.querySelector("#status").innerText = "working";
MyFiveSecondFunctionAsync().done(function () {
    document.querySelector("#status").innerText = "done";
});
document.querySelector("#status").innerText = "free";
```

This is in a button click. I would expect for my status div to very briefly say "working" after I click the button, but then say "free" for 5 seconds and finally say "done" when the 5 second delay is complete. Instead, the UI thread is blocking for 5 seconds and then the status div says "free".

I thought that execution would return to the line that sets status to "free", but debugging shows that it hits the promise function before that. So the status is set to "done" after 5 seconds and then set to "free". In other words, my asynchronous function is just simply not acting asynchronously.

Comment: Promises do not create threads. If you run a spin loop, you will block the UI thread. In particular, the function you pass to `WinJS.Promise` runs synchronously at promise creation, so you are executing your spin loop during construction. It looks like you are trying to create a timeout promise. There's already a Promise.timeout for that.

Comment: Thanks, Raymond! I was misunderstanding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Raymond mentioned in the comment, I was thinking that a promise would create a new thread which is not the case. A promise merely provides a convenient way to "do something when something else is done" as an alternative to specifying a callback function and potentially getting into the Christmas tree issue of nested callbacks.